# How to create supports for the parts hanging above 45 degrees?

Tags: 3d-design, diy-3d-printer, support-structures, open-source

Do you have any specific process recommendations to achieve support for the parts hanging above 45 degrees, using open source software?

Comment: Hi VampishWolf, welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Sorry, but this question cannot be answered as SE is not about product recommendation please read [help] and take the [tour]. All slicer software applications are able to do this for you, some are free (e.g. Ultimaker Cura, Slic3r, etc.). It will be a setting in the huge pile of settings to set the support angle. Alternatively you can create the supports in the program you designed the object in or open the model in a program that can add or change the design.

Comment: As it stands your question is a bit broad so could you clarify your question with a specific example, using a model, images, diagram? We can't really recommend software brands, but process recommendation is permitted. BTW, don't any of the other [support structure](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-structures) questions answer your question?

Comment: I thought the slicer software like Cura or Slic3r did that for you, either automatically or with a minimum of effort. There are plenty of youtube videos to walk you thru using either too. In my famity, we (i.e. my wife) are using Cura at the moment. We've only printed 1 part that needed supports so far, it was a file we found on thingiverse and I don't know if it includede the supports or not in the file that she downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrusaSlicer has **support enforcers** you can place on areas that need support.

See this video: [Prusa Slicer Support Enforcers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqMXfvWA-aY).

#### Automatic supports

There are automatic supports, in the **Supports** dropdown menu, select **Everywhere**:

[image: Supports menu - Everywhere is selected]

Click **Yes** in the resulting dialog:

[image: Click Yes in the dialog]

Click on the **Slice** icon in the bottom left:

[image: Click the Slice icon]

You will end up with a *lot* of supports:

[image: Resulting print with supports]

However, this method generally results in too much support...

#### Custom Suport Enforcers

So turn off **Supports** in the drop down menu, select **None**:

[image: Supports menu - None is selected]

Now, in the **Print Settings** tab, under **Support Material**, disable **Auto Generated Supports** and enable **Generate Support Material**:

[image: Print Settings - Support Material settings]

Then right click on the model and select **Box** from the **Add Support Enforcer** menu item:

[image: Add Support Enforcer - Box menu]

You can move by clicking the **Move** button in the left hand palette,

[image: Move button]

resize by clicking the **Resize** button

[image: Resize button]

and re-shape the **Box** as necessary, to support the difficult overhanging parts parts only. Here we can see three boxes have been added - pale blue for the previously added boxes and green for the current box:

[image: Three Support Enforcer Boxes added]

And a fourth final **Box** for the tail:

[image: Fourth Support Enforcer Boxes added]

Now, when you hit the **Slice** button, there will be much less support structure than when using Automatic supports:

[image: Reduced amount of support structure]

Parts of the model that the slicer thinks still needs support will be highlighted in dark blue (such as the elbow and back of the head):

[image: Unsupported parts highlighted in dark blue]

Add a cylinder support enforcer:

[image: Add Support Enforcer - Cylinder menu]

Resize and re-shape as before and move into position below the elbow:

[image: Putting cylinder support enforcer in place]

Adding a second cylinder as a support enforcer

[image: Putting second cylinder support enforcer in place]

Upon hitting **Slice**:

[image: Final supports]

Now in **Print Settings** - **Support Material** - **Pattern** change it from **Rectilinear** to **Rectilinear Grid**:

[image: Print Settings - Support Material - Pattern settings]

For prints with curves and details **Rectilinear Grid** works better, than **Rectilinear** (which is fine for supporting a plain cube in the air). It is easier to break the support off the print.

Now save your hard work as an AMF file:

[image: Save the enforcers as AMF]

This file maintains all of the support enforcers so that they can be modified if the actual print needs some adjustments - without having to re-add all of the support enforcers all over again.

Comment: I've updated your answer for you :-)

Comment: @Greenonline You've been busy! Nice addition to the answer.

Comment: @Greenonline Perhaps it's better to make your own answer when editing that much though...

Comment: @Jeroen3, Yes, sorry about that but you found the video and I didn't want to take credit for that... :-) I must admit that when I started adding info I didn't realise that there would be so much of it! I expected only one or two screenshots. Lol. But yes, you are right, for such extensive edits, it would have been better for me to refer to your answer and add the process as my own answer. Ah well, next time I will. Thanks for finding the link anyway... it was a useful learning experience :-)